# Why is there not a constructor for List<T> that takes a params argument?

Tags: c#, collections, parameters

I know I can use a collection initializer to initialize a list:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "test string 1",
    "test string 2"
};
```

If I recall, this internally calls Add for each item.

Why is there not a constructor for `List<T>` that takes a `params T[] items`?

```
var list = new List<string>("test string 1", "test string 2");
```

Comment: Why *should* there be such a constructor?

Comment: You can do: `new List<string>(new[]{"test string 1", "test string 2"});` if you dont want to use the collection initializer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The real reason is that the designers simply didn't feel that the benefit of this little bit of syntactic sugar was worth the effort of implementing or that it *might* cause some confusion.

There is a slight issue if you want create a `List<int>`. What should this mean?

```
var list = new List<int>(10);
```

Is that a new list with capacity 10, or a new list containing a single element, 10?

<sub>Spoiler, if you're not sure how the compiler will interpret it:</sub>

> It will be treated as a capacity. If `T` is anything other than `int`, it will be treated as a single element. It would also be treated as a single item if you specify the parameter name—`List<int>(items:10)`

In any case, there's no reason you couldn't just write:

```
var list = new List<string>(new[] { "test string 1", "test string 2" });
```

This is exactly what the compiler would do if there *had* been a constructor that provided a `params` argument, and this is indeed slightly more efficient than the collection initializer. Having to type a few extra characters to accomplish this really isn't that big of a deal in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: +1 - Good point about the capacity parameter - I hadn't thought of that

Comment: although named parameters does kinda address that issue (but `List<T>` was 2 and named parameters was 4...  I think )

Comment: @smartcaveman Actually, I think the fact that adding a named parameter will change the behavior of the code is actually a good argument for *not* including it--`new List<int>(10)` would not be the same as `new List<int>(items:10)` (if there were such a constructor). I'm sure that would lead to a few SO questions, "Why is my list empty when I remove this parameter name?"

Comment: That's definitely a valid point.  Personally, I'm big on explicit semantics, but I do recognize that's a stylistic thing and changing functionality based on a parameter name is definitely not an obvious behavior.

Answer (score 8):

... because there isn't a compelling case to create one? In particular, there is no way of knowing that `params` was used *as `params`*, rather than just by passing a `string[]` in, so it wouldn't be able to trust that array as the backing array - so it would be an additional and unnecessary allocation of a vector. And the collection initializer syntax works pretty nicely. If you want it allocated at the correct size, you can always use:

```
var list = new List<string>(2)
{
    "test string 1",
    "test string 2"
};
```

although frankly, the number of times where this would be important is *really* small.

Actually, I spend a lot of time **removing** `params` usage. On a busy site, it is measurably painful (when used in a hot code path).

Comment: In what way is it painful? Performance? What is a hot code path? One that is hit a lot?

Comment: @Bob yes - by a hot code path I mean one that is used a lot. By painful - I mean that memory profiling on a busy site like stackoverflow can reveal too much memory being wasted on an unnecessary overhead. I don't mind using memory - I just want it used for things that are useful.

Answer (score 3):

### [Because nobody implemented it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx)

Furthermore, it's unnecessary because of collection initializer syntax, which is roughly equivalent (see @p.s.w.g.'s answer)

But! Wait...  I'm feeling so generous, so consider this a gift from me to you:

```
public class SpecialListJustForYou<T> : List<T>
{
    public SpecialListJustForYou(int capacity):base(capacity){}
    public SpecialListJustForYou(IEnumerable<T> collection):base(collection){}
    public SpecialListJustForYou():base(){}

    // and here's the magic!
    public SpecialListJustForYou(params T[] items) : base(items == null ? Enumerable.Empty<T>() : items.AsEnumerable()){}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this has been downvoted so heavily. It's technically correct, although you could go into more detail about *why*.

Comment: @p.s.w.g It's what all the cool kids are doing.  If I could vote on my own answer I'd do it too